# Otimization removing elements from a list defined by another list in Java

Tags: java, list, linked-list

My code is working, but the complexity is quadratic and I have been struggling to figure out how to improve it. I had to create a method to remove elements contained in a list from another list, the final test the list would be 50.000 elements long and the list of elements to remove would be 100 long.

This is the method I created:

```
public void remove(SingleLinkedList<T> toRemove){
       for(int j=0; j<toRemove.size; j++){
           Node<T> remC = toRemove.getN(j);
           if(toRemove.isEmpty()){
               break;
           }
           for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
               Node<T> prev = getN(i-1);
               Node<T> cur = getN(i);
               Node<T> next = getN(i+1);
               if(isEmpty()){
                   break;
               }
               if(remC.getValue().equals(cur.getValue())){
                   if(cur.getValue().equals(getFirst())){
                       removeFirst();
                       i--;
                   }else if(cur.getValue().equals(getLast())){
                       removeLast();
                       i--;
                   }else {
                       prev.setNext(next); //remove node cur
                       size--;
                       i--;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

This is working but exceeds the time limit for the case with 50.000 elements list x 100 elements toRemove list, what I am trying to do there is at the first for loop I save the node with position j in the toRemove list and at the seccond for loop I check if the node of the main list with position i equals to it, and if so I remove it, otherwise I move to next node.

Any ideas?

Comment: *Hint:* **Do not use `getN()`.** With that hint, it means you need to re-think the entire logic, so no more hints, for now.

Comment: Hav you tried to find out which part of your code needs much time? E.g. by counting the number of steps of each line of code or by using a profiling tool like VisualVM.

Comment: @Martin the thing is that I don't have access to the 50k long list test, so I can't really...

Comment: @Andreas I wasn't before, I was using Node<T> rem = first; and working around that, but had the same issue, perhaps I made it worse with this?

Answer (score -1):

I got this done, as Andreas suggested I got rid of the `getN()`'s, but that alone didn´t solve the issue so I made one loop outside the `"i" for` just to get rid of the first elements if they were inside the `toRemove` list (used `.contains()` for that), got rid of the `"j" for`, and then on my for loop I only had to deal with the elements inside the linked list, and the idea was that the `curr node` would be `node 0`, acting as `prev node`, so I would aways search around `cur.getNext()`, since I made sure `node 0` wasn't inside `toRemove` because of the first loop outside the `for`.

It worked fine without having to loop though the positions of the list every time, and even though this is not linear, at least is not quadratic so was good enough for the 50k list test.

:)